# How to create custom plugin like references in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

If you have used visual studio then you are aware that it will display no references particular method has and even display same for class and fields. I want to create such plugin or extends the same plugin so additional information can be available with those information.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can get some help from this sample: [CodeLensOopProvider](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/CodeLensOopSample#codelensoopprovider-example)